# How to use ASP.NET Resources in this way?

Tags: asp.net, resources

I am doing some labeling. I would like to add a resource key (s, sec) to one of my combo boxes with item[3sec, 5sec, 10sec, 30sec ...] and use it like:

```
Text="3<%$ Resources: myResource, s%>" to get comboBoxItem 3sec,
Text="5<%$ Resources: myResource, s%>" to get comboBoxItem 5sec ...
```

But I find that the server will treat this as plain text.

Do I need to define each item in a separate resource key pair?

Answer (score 2):

Consider defining your resource file entry value as follows:

```
{0}sec
```

And then

```
String.Format(Resources.myResource.s, "3")
```

Comment: How are you going to write this in the aspx/ascx page?

Comment: Perhaps like : `<%# String.Format("3{0}", Resources.myResource.s) %>`. I don't know if Ben's method works, but if it does, would be a pretty cool way. +1

Comment: I should have been more clear. This would need to be a code-behind operation.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this (with a DataBind() call somewhere):

```
Text='<%# "3" + Resources.myResource.s %>'
```

**Edit**: You can also do this from code behind. Something like this:

```
int[] times = new int[]{ 3, 5, 10, 30 };
foreach (int time in times)
{
    string text = time.ToString() + Resources.myResource.s;
    cbo.Items.Add(new ListItem(text, time.ToString()));
}
```

**Edit 2**: As per Muhammad's observation the first example doesn't work for this. I've used it for other controls, and I didn't see that for the current case it's not correct. Given this I would fill the control from code behind.

Comment: I have checked, this is giving error..Text='<%# "3" + Resources.myResource.s %>'

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating your own [custom expression builder](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020111734/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/030409-1.aspx). They are really powerful if you want to achieve what you have asked in your question.

Or, you can always do it using server-side code.